# Download multiple files form an online directory

Tags: r, rvest

I have the following website: https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod
and I wanted to download all the files from 2021 to 2023.
Once you enter to the website you can choose between different folders but now I only want to focus en the 2023 one and download all the files in that folder.

I've try using loops and the rvest package with no avail. I want to be able to download all files in the 2023 folder but I can't find my way around the code.
Please help.

Extra Info:

So the code I use is a very basic one since I'm just starting to work with more complex task in R, here is what I tried.

```
IOD <- read_html("https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=Post%20Operaci%C3%B3n%2FReportes%2FIEOD%2F2023%2F")
urls <- IOD %>% 
  html_nodes('context-menu-list-context-menu-root') %>%    # get all `area` nodes
  html_attr('href') %>%    # get the link attribute of each node
  sub('.htm$', '.zip', .) %>%    # change file suffix
  paste0('https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod', .)    # append to base URL

# create a directory for it all
dir <- file.path(tempdir(), 'COES')
dir.create(dir)

lapply(urls, function(url) download.file(url, file.path(dir, basename(url))))

# check it's there
list.files(dir)
```

Once I run that code the outputs were:

```r
IOD <- read_html("https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=Post%20Operaci%C3%B3n%2FReportes%2FIEOD%2F2023%2F")
urls <- IOD %>% 
  html_nodes('context-menu-list-context-menu-root') %>%
     # get all `area` nodes
  html_attr('href') %>%
     # get the link attribute of each node
  sub('.htm$', '.zip', .) %>%
     # change file suffix
  paste0('https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod', .)    # append to base URL

# create a directory for it all
dir <- file.path(tempdir(), 'COES')
dir.create(dir)
# Warning message:
# In dir.create(dir) :
#   'C:\Users\RCV\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0AUH8C\COES' already exists

lapply(urls, function(url) download.file(url, file.path(dir, basename(url))))
# probando la URL 'https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod'
# Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length 48185 bytes (47 KB)
# downloaded 47 KB
# [[1]]
# [1] 0

# check it's there
list.files(dir)
# [1] "Ieod"  "Ieod#"
```

I'm actually lost on what to do to be honest.
Sorry is this is kinda of a basic question.

Comment: The `rvest` documentation should be decent enough to start the process, falling back to a `for` loop to iterate over individual files should be straight-forward once you've isolated the specific elements. You said you tried something, please show us what you tried and where the warnings/errors/bad-data appeared.

Comment: Just udpated with the new information

Comment: I do not understand the `urls <- ...` part. Notice that `IOD %>% html_nodes('context-menu-list-context-menu-root')` returns `{xml_nodeset (0)}` and does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt with `rvest::read_html_live()`:

First of all we have to get monthly links:

```r
url <- "https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=Post%20Operaci%C3%B3n%2FReportes%2FIEOD%2F2023%2F"

ses <- rvest::read_html_live(url)
# ses$view()

months <- ses |>
  rvest::html_elements(xpath = "//li[contains(@id, \"Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023\")]") |>
  rvest::html_attr("id")

months <- paste0("https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=", months)

months[[1]]
# [1] "https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/"
```

Now, for each month you have to get daily links (below just an example for one month, you should extend it using lapply or other iteration):

```r
ses <- rvest::read_html_live(months[[1]])

days <- ses |>
  rvest::html_elements(xpath = "//a[contains(@id, \"Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/\")]") |>
  rvest::html_attr("id")

daily_urls <- paste0("https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=", days)
daily_urls[[1]]
# [1] "https://www.coes.org.pe/Portal/PostOperacion/Reportes/Ieod?path=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/"
```

Now, we have a link to particular day (31) in month (December). We have to extract the table from this page like:

```r
ses <- rvest::read_html_live(daily_urls[[1]])

t <- ses |>
  rvest::html_elements(xpath = "//*[@id=\"tbDocumentLibrary\"]") |>
  rvest::html_table() |>
  purrr::pluck(1)
```

And build the urls to single files:

```r
paste0("https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=", days[[1]], t$Nombre)
# [1] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Dom_3112.pdf"               
# [2] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo6_CMgCP_3112.zip"      
# [3] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo5_Manttoejec_3112.xls" 
# [4] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo4_Hop_3112.xlsx"       
# [5] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo3_RPFyRSF_3112.xlsx"   
# [6] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo2_Hidrologia_3112.xlsx"
# [7] "https://www.coes.org.pe/portal/browser/download?url=Post Operación/Reportes/IEOD/2023/12_Diciembre/31/Anexo1_Resumen_3112.xlsx"
```

Please note, it requires another iteration. In total 4 iterations: 1/ year, 2/ month, 3/ day, 4/ single files.